# Schedule .bat file without using Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a .bat file with 1 parameter that must be scheduled. Unfortunately I cannot use Windows Task Scheduler, nor third-party apps since the computer/s that will need the scheduled .bat file do not have admin rights (company laptop to be specific).

Is there a way to automate the .bat file to run like say once a week?

Comment: Depending on what version of Windows you are running you could try the AT comnand but it is deprecated in newer versions of Windows.

Comment: @Squashman - I believe the users for the app would be using Windows 7 most likely, with a small chance of Windows 8. Could you give me a short example that will run "C:/Directory/file.bat" with a parameter "--context_param directory"D:/Directory" every Friday 9pm?

Comment: Th AT command is not available in Windows 8. I am not sure if the schtasks.exe will work if the user does not have permissions. Not even sure if the AT command would work either without permissions.

Comment: @Squashman - I see, then I guess AT is out of the choices, do you have any other possible suggestions regarding this matter?